# Reading heroku logs from within the app and not externally

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, logging

I am wrote an admin panel app in Laravel and one of its screens needs to show the latest app logs which is hosted on heroku.

Is there any easy way to read the app logs from within the app itself?

The command "heroku logs" does not work inside the heroku bash itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mezmo add-on on the Heroku to store your in-app logs. You can track your logs easily by clicking the Mezmo item in the Heroku's Installed add-ons. There is a free plan also. Hope this help!